# Unable to get data from REST Calls using Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, rest

I am making a REST API call from my php and Node.js application to a particular URL provided by the client which returns a Json object. It works fine from with the PHP. However, I am unable to receive data from my node application? What might be the possible reason can someone help me ?

Note: I have pasted a dummy REST URI for security reasons

1. It works fine with PHP infact i get the json formatted data in like couple of seconds.

> $response =
>   file_get_contents('http://xyz.net/v2_resmgr/providers/pools');  echo
>   $response;

1. I try the same url using node.js i get a TimeOut error. I also tried setting the timeout but it would still not work.

> var job = new CronJob({
>         cronTime: '0 */3 * * * *',
>         onTick: function () {
>
> ```
>   url=   "http://xyznet/v2_resmgr/providers/pools"; 
>
>
>     var request = http.get(url, function (response) {
>
>       var buffer = "",
>         data,
>         route;
>
>       response.on("data", function (chunk) {
>         buffer += chunk;
>       });
>
>       response.on("end", function (err) {
>       console.log(buffer);
>
>     });
>
> request.setTimeout( 200000, function( ) {
>     // handle timeout here
>   console.log("Time Out call to the Rest API");
> });
>
>       });
>
>   },
>   start: true
>
> });
> job.start();
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the answer you are looking for, but life gets easier when you use the 'request' package (https://www.npmjs.org/package/request)

Here is what the code would look like using the request module:

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://xyznet/v2_resmgr/providers/pools', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Print the body of the response.
  }
})
```

---

**Update:** I coded something a little closer to your post. The code below does not use the "request" module and it contacts the server every 3 seconds.

```
setInterval(function () {
    http.get('http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value', function (response) {
        var responseBody = '';
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            responseBody += chunk;
        });
        response.on('end', function () {
            console.log(responseBody);
            var object = JSON.parse(responseBody)
        });
    });
}, 3000);
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning request.  99% of the time it makes your life easier.